# Possible to move a rebase onto a new branch before completing the rebase?

Tags: git

The rebase is huge, and there might actually be error. I could finish the rebase, and if there's error I could erase and pull the remote branch and start over, but that's a lot of work. Is it possible to move an in-progress rebase to a new branch, so that when it is finished I can compare the new branch to the other branch?

EDIT: Nevermind. After thinking a little more, I guess this question is moot because I can simply finish the rebase, then fork to a new branch, the reset the other branch by deleting all the new commits and pulling remote back into it, which will leave me in the same result as I was asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question as asked is simple: no, you cannot shift the rebase while in the middle of that rebase.  You must either complete it, or use `git rebase --abort` to discard your work-so-far.

Using `git rebase --abort` is probably not what you want.  (You *can* recover commits you made up to the abort point, but it is a bit painful: they are in the reflogs but their reflog messages match the original commits' messages, which as I have noted before is like being at a party where everyone is named Bruce: it's hard to find Bruce when Bruce, Bruce, and Bruce are all in the way.)  So you should probably just finish the rebase.

As you already noted, you can just get another copy of the original repository.  But there is something even easier.

Remember, first, that rebasing is fundamentally a *copy* operation.  You take some original sequence of commits:

```
        A - B - C - D    <-- yourbranch (your commits)
       /
... - * - E -...- Z      <-- their commits
```

and you *copy* yours (everything from the tip of your branch, commit `D`, back to but not including the merge base `*`) to new commits that you tack on after their last one:

```
        A - B - C - D            <-- your original commits
       /
... - * - E -...- Z              <-- their commits
                   \
                    A'-B'-C'-D'  <-- your new copies
```

The last step of a regular `git rebase` is that git peels your branch label off your original commit chain, and pastes it on the end of your new copies.

All you need is to find (or paste-on) a label pointing to your original branch tip.  You can do this mid-rebase by using your original branch name to make a new branch:

```
git branch save-pre-rebase yourbranch
```

This changes the in-progress picture to:

```
        A - B - C - D            <-- yourbranch, save-pre-rebase
       /
... - * - E -...- Z              <-- their commits
                   \
                    A'-B'        <-- HEAD
```

(assuming you are at the point where `B` is copied to `B'` but `C` is not yet copied).  Now when git peels off the `yourbranch` name and pastes it on `D'` later, the name `save-pre-rebase` is still around pointing to the original `D`.

You don't even have to do this, though!  When git moves the name `yourbranch` it also leaves `ORIG_HEAD` behind, pointing to the commit `yourbranch` used to point-to.  And, `yourbranch@{1}` is in your reflogs, pointing to the place `yourbranch` used to point-to.  (This particular reflog entry has the same "Bruce problem", but this time you know that the *one particular* Bruce you want is right next to the Bruce who is right next to you.  At least, he is until you update your branch again, possibly inserting another guy named Bruce.)

(If you want to hang on to `ORIG_HEAD` longer than just a quick look, it is wise to create a new branch or tag name, since the *next* rebase will replace it.)